# WooCommerce pdf attachment to custom email is not working

Tags: email, woocommerce, hook, attachment, status

I am using WooCommerce order status manager plugin for custom order statuses and emails notifications. I have created custom status for paid orders via card pay - `card-on-hold`. 
I have also created custom email which will be triggered when statuses will change from `receivet` to `card-on-hold`.

my code is:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_attachments', 'attach_manual_pdf_to_email', 10, 3);
    
function attach_manual_pdf_to_email ( $attachments, $status , $order ) {
    
    $allowed_statuses = array( 'customer_processing_order', 'customer_on_hold_order', 'customer_order_status_email' );
    
    if( isset( $status ) && in_array ( $status, $allowed_statuses ) ) {
        $dokument = get_template_directory() . '/woocommerce/emails/attach.pdf';
        $attachments = $dokument;
    }
    return $attachments;
}
```

Email Ids `customer_processing_order` and `customer_on_hold_order` works like a charm.

But `customer_order_status_email` which is php template for order status manager is not working. It is located in `betheme/woocommerce/emails/customer-order-status-email.php` and I did also try to move it to same locations where other templates are but that did not help.

Any idea how to make this working please?

Comment: Maybe because `customer_order_status_email` is not an order status but a template file name…

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/print-invoices-packing-slip-labels-for-woocommerce/

Comment: Yes i know about those plugins but i do not want to use invoice, packing slips and so on in attachment nothing to connect to woocommerce at all. just simple pdf with manual.

Comment: LoicTheAztec - problem might be that my custom email is triggered when status of order will change from received to card-on-hold. i tried to use card_on_hold but it was not working also tried customer_card_on_hold_order. I have no idea what should be the status then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay i did find a solution:

i did use `echo '<pre>'; print_r($email->id); echo '</pre>'` in template of an email which printed me an email ID. i used this id in my allowed statuses and it is working now.